# AM/PM deleted from Time when separating date and time from a date-time column

Tags: r, tidyr

I am now working on a dataset that uses a date time (MM/DD/YYYY HH:00:00 A/PM) format to save timeframe, I would like to look into insight in the intervals in hours, but after using separate, the AM/PM part of the date had disappeared, how can I code to make the A/PM remain?

My code is as below:

```
hourlyCalories_merged %>%
  separate(ActivityHour, c("ActivityDay", "ActivityHour_sep"), sep=" ")
```

and it transformed the data from

Activity Hour - MM/DD/YYYY HH:00:00 A/PM

to

Activity Day - MM/DD/YYYY
and
ActivityHour_sep - HH:00:00

only.

while my expected output of ActivityHour_sep is HH:00:00 A/PM

Comment: Please share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with an example input and your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are two spaces in the time stamp, you may want to split by `"\\s(?=\\d)"`, space followed by a digit, in order to get two pieces instead of three.

```
df |>
  tidyr::separate(ActivityHour, c("ActivityDay"," ActivityHour_sep"), sep="\\s(?=\\d)")
#    ActivityDay  ActivityHour_sep         X
# 1   04/10/2023       12:32:25 AM 0.9148060
# 2   04/10/2023       12:32:26 AM 0.9370754
# 3   04/10/2023       12:32:27 AM 0.2861395
# 4   04/10/2023       12:32:28 AM 0.8304476
# 5   04/10/2023       12:32:29 AM 0.6417455
# 6   04/10/2023       12:32:30 AM 0.5190959
# 7   04/10/2023       12:32:31 AM 0.7365883
# 8   04/10/2023       12:32:32 AM 0.1346666
# 9   04/10/2023       12:32:33 AM 0.6569923
# 10  04/10/2023       12:32:34 AM 0.7050648
# 11  04/10/2023       12:32:35 AM 0.4577418
```

Base R solution (about 20% faster):

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(df$ActivityHour, "\\s(?=\\d)", perl=TRUE)) |> 
  setNames(c("ActivityDay"," ActivityHour_sep")) |>
  cbind(df[setdiff(names(df), 'ActivityHour')])
#    ActivityDay  ActivityHour_sep         X
# 1   04/10/2023       12:32:25 AM 0.9148060
# 2   04/10/2023       12:32:26 AM 0.9370754
# 3   04/10/2023       12:32:27 AM 0.2861395
# 4   04/10/2023       12:32:28 AM 0.8304476
# 5   04/10/2023       12:32:29 AM 0.6417455
# 6   04/10/2023       12:32:30 AM 0.5190959
# 7   04/10/2023       12:32:31 AM 0.7365883
# 8   04/10/2023       12:32:32 AM 0.1346666
# 9   04/10/2023       12:32:33 AM 0.6569923
# 10  04/10/2023       12:32:34 AM 0.7050648
# 11  04/10/2023       12:32:35 AM 0.4577418
```

**However,** it might be better to use the `POSIX` format instead of time in character format so that you can perform time calculations. You can use `strptime` for that.

```
df <- transform(df, ActivityHour=strptime(ActivityHour, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p', tz='GMT'))
df
#           ActivityHour         X
# 1  2023-04-10 00:32:25 0.9148060
# 2  2023-04-10 00:32:26 0.9370754
# 3  2023-04-10 00:32:27 0.2861395
# 4  2023-04-10 00:32:28 0.8304476
# 5  2023-04-10 00:32:29 0.6417455
# 6  2023-04-10 00:32:30 0.5190959
# 7  2023-04-10 00:32:31 0.7365883
# 8  2023-04-10 00:32:32 0.1346666
# 9  2023-04-10 00:32:33 0.6569923
# 10 2023-04-10 00:32:34 0.7050648
# 11 2023-04-10 00:32:35 0.4577418
```

where

```
class(df$ActivityHour)
# [1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(ActivityHour = c("04/10/2023 12:32:25 AM", "04/10/2023 12:32:26 AM", 
"04/10/2023 12:32:27 AM", "04/10/2023 12:32:28 AM", "04/10/2023 12:32:29 AM", 
"04/10/2023 12:32:30 AM", "04/10/2023 12:32:31 AM", "04/10/2023 12:32:32 AM", 
"04/10/2023 12:32:33 AM", "04/10/2023 12:32:34 AM", "04/10/2023 12:32:35 AM"
), X = c(0.914806043496355, 0.937075413297862, 0.286139534786344, 
0.830447626067325, 0.641745518893003, 0.519095949130133, 0.736588314641267, 
0.13466659723781, 0.656992290401831, 0.705064784036949, 0.45774177624844
)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```